# Android Multiple Bluetooth connections

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I've found some posts pointing that a few Android devices can pair only with one device only and another ones can pair with multiple devices.

**Question:** Can I discover how many devices one can pair with programmatically?